# Remove one element in array of document MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongo-shell

I have database in MongoDB like this

```
{"_id":{"$oid":"5eb8c55230cb8651e0906d7e"},"rolecode":"DHBK_ROLE_01","functioncode":"DHBK_FUNC_01, DHBK_FUNC_02","productid":"mBaaS_Platform","comid":"DHBK"}
{"_id":{"$oid":"5eb8c5a030cb8651e0906d7f"},"rolecode":"DHBK_ROLE_02","functioncode":"DHBK_FUNC_02, DHBK_FUNC_03","productid":"GIS_Platform","comid":"DHBK"}
{"_id":{"$oid":"5ebe0016b4146803d8ad2559"},"rolecode":"DHKT_ROLE_01","functioncode":"DHKT_FUNC_01, DHKT_FUNC_02","productid":"mBaaS_Platform","comid":"DHKT"}
{"_id":{"$oid":"5ebe003cb4146803d8ad255a"},"rolecode":"DHKT_ROLE_02","functioncode":"DHKT_FUNC_01","productid":"Analysis_Platform","comid":"DHKT"}
{"_id":{"$oid":"5ebe00ffb4146803d8ad255b"},"rolecode":"DHBK_ROLE_03","functioncode":"DHBK_FUNC_01, DHBK_FUNC_02,DHBK_FUNC_03","productid":"IOT_Platform","comid":"DHBK"}
{"_id":{"$oid":"5ecf89f969f07e1cb0ad063d"},"rolecode":"DHBK1_ROLE_01","functioncode":"DHBK1_FUNC_1,DHBK_FUNC_03","productid":"IOT_Platform","comid":"DHBK1"}
{"_id":{"$oid":"5ecf8b6169f07e1cb0ad063e"},"rolecode":"DHBK1_ROLE_02","functioncode":"DHBK1_FUNC_1,DHBK_FUNC_02","productid":"SSO_Platform","comid":"DHBK1"}
{"_id":{"$oid":"5ecf8b7969f07e1cb0ad063f"},"rolecode":"DHBK1_ROLE_03","functioncode":"","productid":"ABC_Platform","comid":"DHBK1"}
{"_id":{"$oid":"5ed0cb4cb8d5570916d1ee7e"},"rolecode":"DHBK1_ROLE_05","productid":"XYZ_Platform","functioncodelist":["DHBK1_FUNC_1","DHBK1_FUNC_2","DHBK1_FUNC_3","DHBK1_FUNC_4"],"comid":"DHBK1"}
{"_id":{"$oid":"5ed0cc67b8d5570916d1ef86"},"rolecode":"DHBK1_ROLE_06","productid":"LAM_Platform","functioncodelist":["DHBK1_FUNC_1","DHBK1_FUNC_2","DHBK1_FUNC_3"],"comid":"DHBK1"}
{"_id":{"$oid":"5ed0d23cb8d5570916d1f4c8"},"rolecode":"DHBK1_ROLE_09","productid":"LAM_Platform","functioncodelist":["DHBK1_FUNC_1"],"comid":"DHBK1"}
```

I have Mongo shell to find all document have `DHBK1_FUNC_1` in `functioncodelist` properties.

Here is my Mongo shell

`db.company_role_function.find( { functioncodelist: { $all: ["DHBK1_FUNC_1"] } } )`

And this is the result

```
{"_id":{"$oid":"5ed0cb4cb8d5570916d1ee7e"},"rolecode":"DHBK1_ROLE_05","productid":"XYZ_Platform","functioncodelist":["DHBK1_FUNC_1","DHBK1_FUNC_2","DHBK1_FUNC_3","DHBK1_FUNC_4"],"comid":"DHBK1"}
{"_id":{"$oid":"5ed0cc67b8d5570916d1ef86"},"rolecode":"DHBK1_ROLE_06","productid":"LAM_Platform","functioncodelist":["DHBK1_FUNC_1","DHBK1_FUNC_2","DHBK1_FUNC_3"],"comid":"DHBK1"}
{"_id":{"$oid":"5ed0d23cb8d5570916d1f4c8"},"rolecode":"DHBK1_ROLE_09","productid":"LAM_Platform","functioncodelist":["DHBK1_FUNC_1"],"comid":"DHBK1"}
```

Now I want to remove value DHBK1_FUNC_1 in that result. I hope my result after delete action like this

```
{"_id":{"$oid":"5ed0cb4cb8d5570916d1ee7e"},"rolecode":"DHBK1_ROLE_05","productid":"XYZ_Platform","functioncodelist":["DHBK1_FUNC_2","DHBK1_FUNC_3","DHBK1_FUNC_4"],"comid":"DHBK1"}
{"_id":{"$oid":"5ed0cc67b8d5570916d1ef86"},"rolecode":"DHBK1_ROLE_06","productid":"LAM_Platform","functioncodelist":["DHBK1_FUNC_2","DHBK1_FUNC_3"],"comid":"DHBK1"}
{"_id":{"$oid":"5ed0d23cb8d5570916d1f4c8"},"rolecode":"DHBK1_ROLE_09","productid":"LAM_Platform","functioncodelist":[""],"comid":"DHBK1"}
```

Thank in advanced

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`$pull`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/) operator to achieve this.

```js
db.company_role_function.update(
  { },
  { $pull: { functioncodelist: { $in: ['DHBK1_FUNC_1'] }}},
  { multi: true }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{"_id":{"$oid":"5ed0cb4cb8d5570916d1ee7e"},"rolecode":"DHBK1_ROLE_05","productid":"XYZ_Platform","functioncodelist":["DHBK1_FUNC_1","DHBK1_FUNC_2","DHBK1_FUNC_3","DHBK1_FUNC_4"],"comid":"DHBK1"}
{"_id":{"$oid":"5ed0cc67b8d5570916d1ef86"},"rolecode":"DHBK1_ROLE_06","productid":"LAM_Platform","functioncodelist":["DHBK1_FUNC_1","DHBK1_FUNC_2","DHBK1_FUNC_3"],"comid":"DHBK1"}
{"_id":{"$oid":"5ed0d23cb8d5570916d1f4c8"},"rolecode":"DHBK1_ROLE_09","productid":"LAM_Platform","functioncodelist":["DHBK1_FUNC_1"],"comid":"DHBK1"}
```

After getting the above result:

```
results.forEach(function(result) {
    let index = result.functioncodelist.indexOf("DHBK1_FUNC_1");
    result.functioncodelist.splice(index, 1);
    result.markModified('functioncodelist');
    result.save();
});
```